# Django inclusion tag takes_context TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: django

Does anybody know how to correct the error when takes_context is used with inclusion tag? I believe the problem may lie with the variable associated with context[] for the template tag output, but I'm not exactly sure what should go inside the bracket.
The logic for rendering is in views.py (\mysite\blog\views.py):

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Post
    def DJ_LastDay(request):
            p = Post.objects.latest('Day')
            posts = Post.objects.filter(Day=p.Day)
            return render(request, 'blog/DJ_LastDay.html', {'posts': posts})
```

The inclusion tag (\mysite\blog\templatetags\index_table.py):

```
from django import template
from blog.models import Post
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('index_table.html', takes_context=True)
def DJ_LastDay(context):
    return {'posts': context['posts']}
```

Parent HTML snippet for the inclusion tag (\mysite\blog\templates\blog\DJ_LastDay.html):

```
    {% block content %} 
    <div id="section" style="white-space:nowrap;">  <!--Margin added to keep element to the right of aside bar-->
        <ul>
            <li>Period to display:</li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:DJ_LastDay' %}">Last Trading Day</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:DJ_LastWk' %}">Last Week</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:DJ_LastMnth' %}">Last Month</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:DJ_LastQtr' %}">Last Quarter</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:DJ_LastYr' %}">Last Year</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        {% load index_table %}
        {% DJ_LastDay %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Child HTML template (\mysite\blog\templates\blog\index_table.html):

```
<table id="myTable" border="8" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:1000px;">
    <caption>DJ Index ({{ posts|length }} symbols returned) - Last Day ({% with posts.0 as 1st %} {{ 1st.Day }} {% endwith %})
    </caption>
    <thead>
    <tr style="color:white;background:black;">
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for post in posts reversed %}
    <tr align="center">
        <td><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/results/?q={{ post.Symbol }}">{{ post.Symbol }}</a></td>
        <td>{% firstof post.LastPrice "N/A" %}</td>
        <td>{% firstof post.Name "N/A" %}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The error is shown as:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /DJ_LastDay/
index_table.html
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to namespace your `index_table.html` template reference further? Have you tried `@register.inclusion_tag('blog/index_table.html', takes_context=True)`

Comment: Ok it's working now, thank you!

Comment: I'll post what I said in my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you didn't adequately namespace your `index_table.html` template.

Try this instead:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/index_table.html', takes_context=True)
```